# SSRS Repeat table for each record of results

Tags: reporting-services, repeat, ssrs-tablix

Apologies if I have missed it anywhere else but I can not find any examples of this.

I am pulling data from sql into SSRS and rather than have one row in a table per record, i want a table/group of tables to replicate per record with the ID field as a table title. Something similar to the below image. Is there an option in SSRS to do this? any help is greatly appreciated.

[wanted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b83In.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a row group based on NoticeNumber. Simply add two headers and group detail.

1. Add a table.
2. Add a row group with the group field being Notice No. Make sure you select the option to add group header.
3. Right click the row header added in 2a and select6 "Add Row|Inside Group Below".
4. Add the number of columns you want for each record.
5. Select all the in the top group header row, right click, and select merge.
6. Add your Notice number to the merge cells.
7. Select the merged cell and set its text alignment to left aligned.
8. Paint all you cells in the row produced in 3 above gray.